# Buscar por id en left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas, dónde necesito sacar datos de ambas buscando por ID de la tabla invoice,
lo estoy haciendo con `LEFT JOIN` de la siguiente forma, pero parece que no busca por ID

```
$sql = "SELECT invoice.CODE, invoice.CREATION_TIME, customer.* 
FROM invoice 
LEFT JOIN customer
ON invoice.ID = '".$_GET["id"]."' AND invoice.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.ID";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu consulta esta incompleta, al momento lo único que hace es:

- Seleccionar que columnas quieres en la salida de datos
- Estableces de que tabla van a salir los datos
- Haces uso de `LEFT JOIN` para obtener los datos de la tabla de la izquierda `customer` que tengan relación o no con al menos un registro de la tabla de la derecha que sería `invoices`

Pero deberías modificar la instrucción que tienes en el `ON` pues ahí solo debería estar escrita la igualación de la llave foránea con la llave primaria

Posterior con el uso de un `WHERE` escribes la condición a cumplir que en este caso es el segmento de consulta que ya tienes donde buscas que el id de la tabla `invoices` sea igual al valor que estás haciendo llegar por `GET`:

Consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT  invoice.CODE, 
                invoice.CREATION_TIME, 
                customer.* 
        FROM invoice 
        LEFT JOIN customer
        ON invoice.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.ID
        WHERE invoice.ID = '".$_GET["id"]."'";
```